# Why does regtol.int() resort my X variable in ascending order?

Tags: r, regression, intervals, linear-regression

I'm pretty new at R, so I guess I must be doing something wrong. I have a dataset named "series" with two columns, V1=CP and V2=CU, and I want to perform a linear regression with CU as the independent variable, and then calculate tolerance intervals using regtol.int (in the "tolerance" package).

So what I do is this:

```
fit=lm(v1~v2,series)
inttol=regtol.int(fit,new.x=NULL,side=2,alpha=0.5,P=0.95)
```

And when I open or view inttol, it appears sorted by the CU value. It's important that the order doesn't change because both CU and CP are time series.

Any help?